# Selenium - Return a new page object representing the destination page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and trying to setup some `PageObjects`. Right now, I have two `PageObjects`: `Login` and `ProjectIndex`. In `Login.rb`, I have a method `successful_login` which fills an email address, then clicks a sign-in button, which shows the project index page. My understanding is that clicking sign-in should return an instance of `ProjectIndex`, but I can't seem to get this working. When the test runs, I get the following error:

```
  1) Login succeeded
      Failure/Error: expect(@project_index.loaded?).to be true
       NoMethodError:
        undefined method `loaded?' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/login_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's my test (in `login_spec.rb`):

```
it 'succeeded' do
 @login.successful_login 'victor@something.com'
 expect(@project_index.loaded?).to be true
end
```

My `/pages/login.rb` file:

```
class Login < Base
 ...
 def successful_login(email)
   send_keys EMAIL_INPUT, email
   click SIGNIN_BUTTON
   @project_index = ProjectIndex.new(@driver)
 end
...
end
```

My `/pages/project_index.rb` file:

```
class ProjectIndex < Base
...
 def loaded?
  wait_for(6) { displayed? NAVIGATION_BAR }
 end
...
end
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `login_spec.rb`, try something like this: (note you need to pass in the driver, unless you are setting @driver in login.rb)

```
 @project_index = @login.successful_login 'victor@something.com', driver
 expect(@project_index.loaded?).to be true
```

And then in `/pages/login.rb` do this:

```
def successful_login(email, driver)
   send_keys EMAIL_INPUT, email
   click SIGNIN_BUTTON
   ProjectIndex.new(driver)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @stytown! It works when I use `@driver` in `login_spec.rb` like so:

`@project_index = @login.successful_login 'victor@honchodesign.com', @driver
expect(@project_index.loaded?).to be true`

Not sure what that means about my setup, but seems to be working ok.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked! Would you mind clicking the checkmark to the left to let people know that your question was answered?